# problem loading image from db pathname

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

image control doesn't seem to load image? Path name is set in db to a picture on my desktop.

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT User.FirstName, User.SecondName, User.Aboutme, User.DOB, Pictures.picturepath FROM User LEFT JOIN Pictures ON User.UserID = Pictures.UserID WHERE User.UserID=1", cn);
OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Name.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
    Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));
    Age.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(3));
    Image1.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(4));
}
```

i've also tried @ which allows me to see the image box but then disappears? Ive checked that visible is set to true.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = String.Format("@{0}", reader.GetString(4));
```

can any one help?

```
<div class="image">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <img style="border-width: 0px;" src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample%20Pictures" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Image1">
    &nbsp;</div>
```

asp

```
<div class="image">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
    &nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: What does the raw value of reader.GetString(4) return?

Comment: Is the path a server path or a relative client-viewable path?  Could be that it just needs to be mapped to a URL.

Comment: @Garrith Graham: Can you show us the output that's being rendered in the browser (the raw HTML for the image)?  I also don't think the `@` is necessarily appropriate there.

Comment: found the problem mysql isnt dealing with spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double check the ImageUrl being set in your example is in-fact the full path to a picture on your desktop.

You can also check the generated html in the browser to see what is being generated, verify there aren't extra escape characters... if the path is in fact still correct, use firebug or fiddler to see if there's another reason the image isn't being returned.

Comment: ive outputed the raw html using firebug still cant figure out what ive did wrong

Comment: found the problem mysql isnt dealing with spaces

Answer (score 1):

seems its a mysql problem, it adds in a % in an space in the relative path rendering it useless.